# Difference between two dates SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm searching a way to get the difference between two times in SQL Server.

I would like a format `hh:mm:ss`

Example : 23:00:00 - 18:09:00 = 04:51:00

I tried with `datediff()` but it only returns hours, minutes or seconds

[EDIT] :

For example : 23:00:00 + 02:00:00 = 01:00:00, how to get 25:00:00?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert to a time:

```
select dateadd(second, datediff(second, date1, date2), cast('0:00:00' as time))
```

You can then use `format()` or `convert()` to format the value as a string the way you want.

Comment: ...as long as the duration is < 24 hours.

Comment: (Also, I think you need `cast('0:00' as time)`.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . Do you know why `0` works for dates and date times, but doesn't work for times?

Comment: New types introduced in 2008 didn't inherit all the sloppiness of the old types. Shorthand like SYSDATETIME() + 1 doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
Declare @T1 time = '23:00'
Declare @T2 time = '18:09'

Select cast(cast(@T1 as datetime) - cast(@T2 as datetime) as time)
```

**Returns**

```
04:51:00.0000000
```

**Or you can use Format() if 2012+**

```
Select format(cast(@T1 as datetime) - cast(@T2 as datetime),'HH:mm:ss')
```

**Returns**

```
04:51:00
```

Comment: It's exactly what I was searching, you make me happy :), thanks

Answer (score 0):

Though Others have already answered correctly. I would like to add another version.

```
declare @StartTime datetime, @EndTime datetime

select @StartTime = '08:40:18',@EndTime='18:52:48'

select  convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @StartTime, @EndTime)/3600)+':'
    +   convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @StartTime, @EndTime)%3600/60)+':'
    +   convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, @StartTime, @EndTime)%60)) as [hh:mm:ss]
```

Output: `10:12:30`

Comment: 23:00:00 + 02:00:00 = 01:00:00, please,  how to get 25:00:00?